# Combine multiple .frameworks in one "umbrella"

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, libtool-xcode

I am currently working on an iOS project with external frameworks.

One of those frameworks contains of 5 .framework files.

Here is an exmaple:

```
core.framework

versionA.core.framework
versionA.resources.framework

versionB.core.framework
versionB.resources.framework
```

What I need is one framework e.g. **umbrellaA.framework** containing this

```
core.framework

versionA.core.framework
versionA.resources.framework
```

and one framework e.g. **umbrellaB.framework** containing versionB

```
core.framework

versionB.core.framework
versionB.resources.framework
```

Can I use libtool for this or what do I need to combine multiple .framework files into one ùmbrella`?

Comment: Please say why you want to do this.

Comment: @hfossli I do have a build script and depending on some parameters I either need a reference to versionA or versionB of the framework (completely different internal structure). Now I do not want to manipulate the xcode project file (link binary with libraries). Instead I would link against one "umbrella" file and replace this umbrella file depending on the input parameters. Thought this would probably be easier than changing the xocode project file

Comment: Could cocoapods be an option?

Comment: Is there any way to use cocoa-pods for packaging multiple frameworks? What I do not want is different targets and I think there would be no other way when using cocoa-pods

Comment: Maybe subspecs is appropriate? I don't understand the "different targets" part you are talking about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use cocoapods and subspecs?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "Umbrella"
    ...

    s.default_subspec = 'A'

    s.subspec 'A' do |ss|
        ss.frameworks        = '.......'
    end

    s.subspec 'B' do |ss|
        ss.frameworks        = '.......'
    end
end
```

If someone wants to use the `Umbrella.A` framework then they refer to it like this in their Podfile

```
pod 'Umbrella/A'
```

Comment: Or you could have one podspec for each (A and B)